# Symfony 2.3 custom form login_check

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have successfully created a login system that checks a doctrine user entity class and authenticates successfully. This uses http_basic which is set in the firewalls block in:

app/config/security.yml

However I wish to use the form_login option and render my own custom login template. Below is the app/config/security.yml after i made changes to use form login which renders my custom form:

```
security:
encoders:
    Brs\UserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    # in_memory:
    #     memory:
    #         users:
    #             user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
    #             admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
    administrators:
        entity: { class: BrsUserBundle:User, property: fname }

firewalls:
    login: 
        pattern: ^/admin/login$
        anonymous: ~
    admin_area:
        pattern: ^/admin/
        # http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Now my form template posts to the check_path defined under form_login in security.yml.

I have the 2 routes defined within the bundle in LoginBundle/config/routing.yml

```
admin:
    path: /admin/login
    defaults: { _controller: BrsLoginBundle:Login:index }

adminlogin:
    path: /admin/login_check
    defaults: { _controller: BrsLoginBundle:Login:loginCheck }

admin_hello:
    path: /admin/hello
    defaults: { _controller: BrsLoginBundle:Login:hello }
```

When i submit the form it will return me to the /admin/login/ url and i cannot seem to get this to authenticate.

From my understanding in the LoginController.php the symfony 2 docs tell me to define the method loginCheckAction(), which is empty and returns nothing.

If i am following this correctly the form posts to the login_check path and the security system should handle the authentication just like when I used http_basic.

I am baffled and I am currently reading the docs again to see if i have missed something silly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Adam

EDIT*

Here is the twig template that renders the form:

```
    {% extends 'BrsLoginBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
       <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData) }}</div>
{% endif %}       {#{form_start(form,{ 'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate' }})}#}
       <form action="{{ path('login_check')}}" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="_username" />
       <input type="password" name="_password" />
       <button type="submit">Login</button>
       </form>
       {#{form_widget(form)}#}
       {#{form_end(form)}#}
{% endblock %}
```

here is the controller

```
<?php
    namespace Brs\LoginBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Brs\LoginBundle\Form\Type\LoginType;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;


    class LoginController extends Controller{

        public function indexAction(Request $request){
            $session = $request->getSession();
            //instantiate the form type to use
            //$login = new LoginType();
            // create the form based on the type above
            //$form = $this->createForm(new LoginType(), $login);
            // this will tell me wether the form was submitted or not and handle the validation defined in bundle/resources/config/validation.yml
            //$form->handleRequest($request);
            //checks if the form is valid then we will execute what we want to next
            //if($form->isValid()){
                //do something if all validation test are passed        
            //} 
            var_dump($request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR));
            var_dump($session->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR));
            var_dump(null !== $session);

            $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);   
            //print_r($request->attributes->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR));
            //print_r($session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR));
            //render the login template and pass the created form to it
            return $this->render('BrsLoginBundle:Admin:login.html.twig',array(
                'name'=>"Login",
                'error'=>$error
                //'form'=>$form->createView(),
            ));
        }

        public function hello(){
            return new Response("i shoudlnt be able to see this");
        }

        public function loginCheckAction(){

        }
    }
?>
```

Here is the link to the documentation that I have been following:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

EDIT*

I have tailed the logs and this is Authenticating the user, However when it calls the login_check method , it then attempts to reload the user from the database but fails to find one. so it starts the login procedure over again. The logs are in the link below:

http://pastebin.com/sfTCNJS7

Comment: can you please share your custom template of login page and the controller that handles the login process, also share the reference where you read login action should be empty and return nothing.

Comment: I have added what you requested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that error is there

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

as to access `/admin/*` routes you're telling to symfony that user has to be already authenticated. This control is done before `/admin/login_check` starts his actions.

You should modify security.yml as follows

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

### EDIT

OP claims that after logout I can't login anymore. I suspect that his logic behind logout isn't good. If you take a look to his logs you can notice that, after second login attempt, Symfony2 reports

> [2015-02-17 14:57:16] security.WARNING: Username "" could not be
>   found. [] []

like no username is passed to login_check action

Comment: Ok, I have added that line to the access_control section, and now it follows the default_target_path parameter which if I'm correct on success redirects to that path I have specified. However within the Symfony profiler I am still not authenticated.

Comment: Yes you were correct i just needed to redirect to the firewalled area to show the auth in the profiler. Thank you.

Comment: It logged in, and authenticated but now i cannot login again. Just returns me to the login path with no errors.

Comment: @Adamski: what do you mean with "cannot login again"?

Comment: When I logged in after i made the change you suggested, It redirected me to the default_target_path set in security.yml and the profiler told me i was authenticated. So I moved on to the logout procedure set in security.yml. Now when i try to login i get no errors just a redirect back to the form login as before. Also if I enter invalid credentials only then will it trigger the failure path which is correct. So this suggests that the credentials are correct its something else tripping it up and i am not sure what it is :-/.

Comment: @Adamski: wait, are you now able to login, right? So, what's the problem. I can't get it. Please, help me understand.

Comment: Sure, sorry if i am not making my self clear. I was able to log in once. When I logged out i am not able to login again, described in my comment above.

Comment: @Adamski: when you logout, where are you redirected?

Comment: In my security.yml under the logout block the path I set was /admin/logout, which then would redirect me to / and the invalidate_session is set to false.

Comment: according to the logs it authenticates the user, then when it hits the login_check method it attempts to reload the user from the session and the query returns nothing. Thats where its tripping up.

Comment: @Adamski: maybe your authentication methods aren't good enaugh but your answer was answer fine by me. I don't know what happens after logout but I know that solution I provided to you is good

Comment: I cannot see it being bad logic as i have not written any, I have just enabled the logout parameter in the form_login block of security.yml

Comment: @Adamski: dind't you implemented logout action?

Comment: No, I thought login_check and logout where handled with the symfony system?

Comment: @Adamski: yes sure, until you change it. I was wondering if you've done, but seems not the case. Strange, because your issue should be elsewhere, it's not original problem anymore and I'm afraid that is derived from your own logic error, somewhere

Comment: You are correct, i'll mark this as answered and start a new question. Thank you for all your help :-).